# How do I convert all the elements of a list to binary in python using bin() method?

Tags: python, list, binary

I have a list `numbers = ['1', '5', '10', '8']` and I want to convert each elements of this list to binary.I tried this code, but it's not working

```
numbers = ['1', '5', '10', '8']
newl=[]
for i in numbers:
    newl.append(bin(i))
print(newl)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This is a case where it's important to describe what's "not working" and read the error message carefully

Answer (score 4):

Since your list contains string you have to convert them to ints first:

```
numbers = ['1', '5', '10', '8']
newl=[]
for i in numbers:
    newl.append(bin(int(i))[2:])
print(newl)  # -> ['1', '101', '1010', '1000']
```

Or with list comprehension in one line:

```
print([bin(int(i))[2:] for i in numbers])    # -> ['1', '101', '1010', '1000']
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked. I was not converting the elements into integer that's the reason I was getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

for int supply an integer not string and the bin prefix 0b so we can remove it with [2:] if needed.

```
>>> list(bin(int(each))[2:] for each in  ['1', '5', '10', '8'])
['1', '101', '1010', '1000']
```

Comment: Thanks, Just provided info pertaining to the solution